# bash to extract and store after second underscore

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `bash` to extract after the second `_` and store that in a variable `pref`. I am using a `loop` so the below is not completely accurate, but the file structure/format is.

I can extract evertything before the first `_` using `pref=${bname%%_*}, but can't seem to change it to the second`_`.  Thank you :).

**file to extract from**

```
00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt
```

**desired output**

```
00-0000_Last-First
```

**bash**

```
 pref=${bname%%_}; pref=${bname%%_*.txt}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cut` with `_` as delimiter get 1st and 2nd fields:

```
s='00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt'
cut -d_ -f1-2 <<< "$s"

00-0000_Last-First
```

To store in a variable:

```
pref=$(cut -d_ -f1-2 <<< "$s")
```

Comment: Thank you both very much for the help, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
$ sed -r 's/([^_]+_[^_]*).*/\1/' <<<"00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt"
00-0000_Last-First

$ sed 's/_[^_]*//2g' <<< "00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt"
00-0000_Last-First

$ grep -o "^[^_]*_\?[^_]*" <<<"00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt"
00-0000_Last-First
```

To store in variable

```
somevar="00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt";
pref=$(sed 's/_[^_]*//2g' <<< "$somevar")
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as with `sed`, `awk` and `cut`, you can achieve this with `expr`:

```
 $ filename=00-0000_Last-First_base_counts_FBN1.txt
 $ echo $(expr match "$filename" '^\([^_]*_[^_]*\)')
 00-0000_Last-First
```

This is echoing the capture group with in the `\(` and `\)` of the regular expression.